# MAC phpmyadmin: How to run the database server with mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So i have installed mariadb using homebrew.

> which mysql

gives me: `/opt/homebrew/bin/mysql`. Currently my mariadb is auto-running at port 3306.

How do I configure the phpmyadmin to use the already running mariadb?

Where is the mariadb socket located?

```
port=3306
socket      =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Does http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ not working on the browser?

Comment: The mariadb is running at 3306, if I start the mysql server from xampp, it will not start because it uses the same port 3306, if I change to 3307 it works, but then, they are 2 instances running, 3306 mariadb and 3307 mysql. I want xampp to run mariadb at 3306

Comment: I think if you wish to use port `3306`, you only set that for the one you needed and disabled it for other one.